# How can I use an assembly function in a C code in Dev C++ compiler ? Error: Undefined reference to `__UADD16'

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I am using Dev C++ compiler to run my C code below. I have used _UADD assembly function to make it more optimized. But I am getting an undefined reference error for _UADD. I have only minimal background in assembly language. Can I use this assembly function _UADD to optimize my C code and compile in Dev C++? If so how?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <x86intrin.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    


#ifndef N1_8_H
#define N1_8_H
    
void refined_karatsuba_mul(int16_t* h, const int16_t* f, const int16_t* g, int n);
#endif
    
  static void schoolbook_mul(int16_t* h, const int16_t* f, const int16_t* g, int n)
    {
      int16_t result; 
      int i,j;
      for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      result = 0;
      for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j) result = result+f[j]*g[i-j];
      h[i] = result; 
      }
      for (i = n; i < n+n-1; ++i) {
        result = 0;
        for (j = i-n+1; j < n; ++j) result = result+f[j]*g[i-j];
        h[i] = result; 
      }
  
    }
   
      void refined_karatsuba_mul(int16_t* h, const int16_t* f, const int16_t* g, int n) {
      const int16_t* f0 = f;
      int16_t f01[n/2];
      const int16_t* f1 = f + n/2;
       const int16_t* g0 = g;
      int16_t g01[n/2];
      const int16_t* g1 = g + n/2;
      uint32_t result;
      for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i+=2) {
        *(int32_t*)(&f01[i]) = __UADD16(*(int32_t*)(&f0[i]), *(int32_t*)(&f1[i])); // f01[i]= f0[i] + f1[i] and f01[i+1]= f0[i+1] + f1[i+1]
        *(int32_t*)(&g01[i]) = __UADD16(*(int32_t*)(&g0[i]), *(int32_t*)(&g1[i])); // g01[i]= g0[i] + g1[i] and g01[i+1]= g0[i+1] + g1[i+1]
      }
    
      int16_t p1[n-1], p2[n-1], p3[n-1];
      schoolbook_mul(p1, f0, g0, n/2);
      schoolbook_mul(p2, f01, g01, n/2);
      schoolbook_mul(p3, f1, g1, n/2);
    

      for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        h[i] += p1[i];
        h[i+n/2] += p2[i] - p1[i] - p3[i];
        h[i+n] += p3[i];
      }
    }
   
int main(){


    int16_t *f = malloc(8*sizeof(int16_t));
    int16_t *g = malloc(8*sizeof(int16_t));
    int16_t *h= calloc((2*8-1), sizeof(int16_t));

     int i;
////////////////////////reading f and g 
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("inp8test", "r");
    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);}

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        fscanf(myFile, "%d", &f[i]);
        f[i] = 0;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        fscanf(myFile, "%d", &g[i] );
        g[i] = 0;
    }
    fclose(myFile);
    

        unsigned long long   LastCycleCount = _rdtsc();
        clock_t start = clock ();        
    for (i=0;i<999;i++){
        
    refined_karatsuba_mul(h, f, g, 8);
        memset(h, 0, sizeof(int16_t)*(2*8-1));
        }
        refined_karatsuba_mul(h, f, g, 8);
        unsigned long long   EndCycleCount = _rdtsc();
        unsigned long long   CyclesElapsed = EndCycleCount - LastCycleCount;
        CyclesElapsed = CyclesElapsed/1000 ;
   
        double Timelapsed=(clock()-start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        Timelapsed=Timelapsed/1000;
 /////////////////////////////////////////////write on c_n1_8 file  
    FILE *outFile;
    outFile = fopen("c_n1_8", "w");
    if (outFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot Open File\n");
        exit (0);
    }
    
   for (i = 0; i < 2*8-1; i++)
        fprintf(outFile, "%d ", ((h[i])%3+3)%3 );
        
    fclose(outFile);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////printing on console
    for( i=0; i<2*8-1; i++)
        printf("%d ", ((h[i])%3+3)%3);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("Cycles: %llu\n", CyclesElapsed);
    printf("Multiplication Time:");
    printf( "%f",Timelapsed);
    printf("sec");
    printf("\n \n ");

    free(f);
    free(g);
    free(h);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `__UADD16`, is it the ARM intrinsic? Yet you have included the header for x86 intrinsics. Is this code for ARM or x86?

Comment: @nicomp  yes it is Arm cortex m4 assebmly code